# Understanding the Real time data with a plotting strategy with Pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am learning Pine script. Now I wanted to plot or a Strategy.Entry on the live bar.

- So I tried having a barmerge.lookahead_on which will also consider
  current Bat for calculations.
- I also put calc_on_every_tick=true
  as my strategy only depends on Open of the bar and does not worry about changing data of current Bar.

```
//@version=4
strategy("RayTrader03 Startegy",overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true)

// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
fromMonth = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Month",      type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromDay   = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Day",        type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromYear  = input(defval = 2019, title = "From Year",       type = input.integer, minval = 1970)
thruMonth = input(defval = 1,    title = "Thru Month",      type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
thruDay   = input(defval = 1,    title = "Thru Day",        type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
thruYear  = input(defval = 2112, title = "Thru Year",       type = input.integer, minval = 1970)

// === INPUT SHOW PLOT ===
showDate  = input(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range", type = input.bool)
// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
start     = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)        // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(thruYear, thruMonth, thruDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false       // create function "within window of time"


//----
ses = change(time("D")) 
o = open,c = close
var symbol = "CCL"
var percentFill = 50
currentOpen = security(symbol, 'D', open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
currentClose = security(symbol, 'D', close,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevClose = security(symbol, 'D', close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevOpen = security(symbol, 'D', open[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevHigh = security(symbol, 'D', high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(currentOpen, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_line, color=color.red)
//----
//myIdealGap = (prevClose < prevOpen) and (currentOpen > (prevClose + ((prevOpen - prevClose)*(percentFill/100))))
myIdealGap = (prevClose < prevOpen) and (currentOpen > (prevOpen + prevClose)/2)
//----
val = myIdealGap ? max(c[1],o[1]) : min(c[1],o[1])
lim = valuewhen(ses and myIdealGap,val,0)  
//----
//strategy.close_all(ses)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=myIdealGap and window())

strategy.exit("Buy", limit=prevHigh)

//----
//plot(lim,"Limit/Stop",#ff1100,2)
```

ok so the entry will be called only after close of current bar, s it will go to next bar.

Is there a way I can plot on live bar as soon as I have the open data for the current bar?

Any help is really appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the full explanation may lay deeper in the engine of Pine itself. My experience is: Studies will mark their marks (labels, for instance) on the very bar the calculation says so, while Strategies will show something on the chart on the very next bar.
Problem is that Studies won't allow you to use built-in things as entry/close/pyramid/backtesting/etc...

Comment: Hey thanks, are you aware of a way to put entry on previous bar as part of Strategy? As it is otherwise a bit difficult to handle same bar calculations

Comment: Hi, no, I'm not. Not sure it is possible. Have a look here:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html#backtesting-and-forwardtesting

I expect you won't be able to backtest your strategy because on history data, timed dynamic intra-bar history is lost and we end up with only static data (high, low, open, close).

Have you tried to put it live and observe the behaviour when live calculating??

Comment: When I tried the logic to calculate works fine and finds the days where I want it to find. But it always enters the trade the next day after I identify the trend. So cannot do a live enter live on current bar. Sorry I am learning pinescript only for last two days, so another question - Can we switch frames in script? Like identify days where I want to get in and actually enter the strategy on 5 minute chart of the day?

Comment: Hi, as far as I know you can use multiple timeframes whitin a script, with certain limitations. I have no experience with that, though.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy try to set up `process_orders_on_close` to `true`